# Vector Rotation About Arbitrary Axis

Tags: vectors

I am new to this forum. I was reading this document : 
http://math.kennesaw.edu/~plaval/math4490/rotgen.pdf

Here the author says that from this figure 
[image]

that we can express $v_{\perp}$ like this : 
$$T (v_{\perp}) = \cos(\theta)  v_{\perp} + \sin(\theta) w$$

I don't understand this part. Can anybody explain how $T(v_{\perp})$ is $\cos(\theta) v_{\perp} + \sin(\theta) w$?

Comment: Basic trigonometry. Do you understand how to convert from rectangular to polar coordinates in the Cartesian plane? Same thing here.

Comment: Hi aaa111. I embedded your image and added MathJax formatting to your post. Please use similar formatting in the future. Use the link provided by Normal Human to learn more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the same thing as rotating through an angle $\theta$ in the $x-y$ plane, except you've defined the axes differently so that they're both perpendicular to the arbitrary axis of rotation.

Your $v_{\perp}$ is the projection of $v$ into the plane of rotation.  The vector $w$ is defined by rotating $v_{\perp}$ in that plane by $90^{\circ}$.

Then the equation starts to look an awful lot like $r' = \hat{x} \cos \theta + \hat{y} \sin \theta.$

Comment: So I can think of the component $\sin(\theta) w$ is equivalent of $\sin(\theta)v_{\perp} $

Comment: Not quite.  $v_{\perp}$ and $w$ should have the same magnitude, but are perpendicular.  They're both vectors.

Comment: Well that make sense.

Comment: One final question. So here in this equation , $T (v_{\perp}) = \cos(\theta)  v_{\perp} + \sin(\theta) w$ is the $v_{\perp}$ is results of addition of its two component vector $\cos(\theta)  v_{\perp}$ and  $\sin(\theta) w $?